# Styling html page?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a custom CMS using php. what I am trying to do is to allow the "Admin" create different HTML pages with different contents!

The page creation is going well but it only goes well if the html page is very basic and has no styling or jquery stuff in it! The HTML pages would have some CSS styling and some javascript and jQuery codes in it too but for some reason having them in the page would stop the HTML page creation in PHP!

**the first code (working one) uses:**

```
`$html = "<html>\n<body>\n<p>Hello world</p>\n</body>\n</html>";`
```

**and the second code (the non working one) uses this:**

```
$html = "the whole HTML page with CSS and javascript/jQuery copy/pasted here";
```

This code works fine:

```
<?
if ($_POST["filename"]) {
error_reporting(0);
$i=1;
while($file = fopen("untitled$i.html", "r")) { fclose($file); $i++; }
if($file = fopen("untitled$i.html", "w")) {
$html = "<html>\n<body>\n<p>Hello world</p>\n</body>\n</html>";
if(fwrite($file, $html) === false) { echo "Could not write"; exit; }
fclose($file);
$newfile=$_POST["filename"].".html";
system("mv untitled$i.html $newfile");
header("Location: $newfile");
}
}
else {
echo "<form method=post action='".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."'>\n";
echo "New File Name: <input name='filename'>\n</form>\n";
}
?>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFDDDD"><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="createpagestest.php" onsubmit="return validate_form2 ( );">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Page" />
      <input name="filename" type="text" id="filename" size="8" maxlength="11" />

      <br />
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but if I do it like this, it won't create any HTML page at all....

```
<?
if ($_POST["filename"]) {
error_reporting(0);
$i=1;
while($file = fopen("untitled$i.html", "r")) { fclose($file); $i++; }
if($file = fopen("untitled$i.html", "w")) {
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <title>My title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="supersized.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
            $.fn.supersized.options = {  
                startwidth: 640,  
                startheight: 480,
                vertical_center: 1,
                slideshow: 1,
                navigation: 1,
                transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
                pause_hover: 0,
                slide_counter: 1,
                slide_captions: 1,
                slide_interval: 6000  
            };
            $('#supersize').supersized(); 
        });
    </script>


</head>

<body >
<div id="Details1">

<div class="txtD">
<h1>HOME</h1>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br /><br  />
</div>
</div>

<div id="CloseButton"><a id="ClosePanel" href="#"><img src="images/close.png" width="15" height="11" /></a></div>

<div id="OpenButton"><a id="OpenPanel" href="#"><img src="images/open.png" width="15" height="11" /></a></div>


<div id="navBarHolder">
        <a href="index_2.html" class="stamp"><img width="200" src="images/logoF.png"/></a>

        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eco statement</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Private</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

         <nav id="nav2">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="20" height="20" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="20" height="20" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pinterest.png" width="20" height="20" alt="instgram" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/rhenvelope.png" width="20" height="20" alt="email" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

<nav id="nav3">
        <ul>
        <li>Tell | 01700000</li>
        <li>Fax | 01700000</li>
        <li>info@site.com</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

<nav id="nav4">
        <ul>
        <li>© site Copyright. All Rights Reserved.</li>

        </ul>
        </nav>

</div>


<!--Loading display while images load-->
<div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>

<!--Slides-->
<div id="supersize">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/bird.jpg" title="Bird On A Branch"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/paradise.jpg" title="Paradise Lost"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/snake.jpg" title="Morelia Viridis"/></a>
</div>

<!--Content area that hovers on top-->
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentframe">

        <!--Logo-->

        <!--Navigation-->
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="#" id="prevslide"><img src="images/back_dull.gif"/></a><a href="#" id="pauseplay"><img src="images/pause_dull.gif"/></a><a href="#" id="nextslide"><img src="images/forward_dull.gif"/></a>



        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    $('#Details1').animate({'left': 200},1000);
});


$(function(){
    $("#ClosePanel").click(function () {

        $("#Details1").animate({'left': -500},500,function(){
           $("#Details1").css('display','none')
           $("#CloseButton").css('display','none')
           $("#OpenButton").css('display','block')
        });
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("#OpenPanel").click(function () {
        $("#Details1").animate({'left': 200},1000,function(){
           $("#Details1").css('display','block')
           $("#CloseButton").css('display','block')
           $("#OpenButton").css('display','none')
        });
    });
});


</script>

</body>
</html>

";
if(fwrite($file, $html) === false) { echo "Could not write"; exit; }
fclose($file);
$newfile=$_POST["filename"].".html";
system("mv untitled$i.html $newfile");
header("Location: $newfile");
}
}
else {
echo "<form method=post action='".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]."'>\n";
echo "New File Name: <input name='filename'>\n</form>\n";
}
?>


<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFDDDD"><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="createpagestest.php" onsubmit="return validate_form2 ( );">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Page" />
      <input name="filename" type="text" id="filename" size="8" maxlength="11" />

      <br />
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

could someone please help me with this?

Comment: you cannot start $html=" and then content here with doubblequotes" you need to backspace them or try to use single and doubble quotes "'

Comment: [Start by using a proper template library like **Smarty** PHP or similar.](http://www.smarty.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this works:

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

    <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <title>My title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/tags/ui/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="supersized.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
            $.fn.supersized.options = {  
                startwidth: 640,  
                startheight: 480,
                vertical_center: 1,
                slideshow: 1,
                navigation: 1,
                transition: 1, //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-slide top, 3-slide right, 4-slide bottom, 5-slide left
                pause_hover: 0,
                slide_counter: 1,
                slide_captions: 1,
                slide_interval: 6000  
            };
            $("#supersize").supersized(); 
        });
    </script>


</head>

<body >
<div id="Details1">

<div class="txtD">
<h1>HOME</h1>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry"s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br /><br  />
</div>
</div>

<div id="CloseButton"><a id="ClosePanel" href="#"><img src="images/close.png" width="15" height="11" /></a></div>

<div id="OpenButton"><a id="OpenPanel" href="#"><img src="images/open.png" width="15" height="11" /></a></div>


<div id="navBarHolder">
        <a href="index_2.html" class="stamp"><img width="200" src="images/logoF.png"/></a>

        <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eco statement</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Private</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

         <nav id="nav2">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="20" height="20" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="20" height="20" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/pinterest.png" width="20" height="20" alt="instgram" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/rhenvelope.png" width="20" height="20" alt="email" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

<nav id="nav3">
        <ul>
        <li>Tell | 01700000</li>
        <li>Fax | 01700000</li>
        <li>info@site.com</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>

<nav id="nav4">
        <ul>
        <li>© site Copyright. All Rights Reserved.</li>

        </ul>
        </nav>

</div>


<!--Loading display while images load-->
<div id="loading">&nbsp;</div>

<!--Slides-->
<div id="supersize">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/bird.jpg" title="Bird On A Branch"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/paradise.jpg" title="Paradise Lost"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/snake.jpg" title="Morelia Viridis"/></a>
</div>

<!--Content area that hovers on top-->
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentframe">

        <!--Logo-->

        <!--Navigation-->
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="#" id="prevslide"><img src="images/back_dull.gif"/></a><a href="#" id="pauseplay"><img src="images/pause_dull.gif"/></a><a href="#" id="nextslide"><img src="images/forward_dull.gif"/></a>



        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    $("#Details1").animate({"left": 200},1000);
});


$(function(){
    $("#ClosePanel").click(function () {

        $("#Details1").animate({"left": -500},500,function(){
           $("#Details1").css("display","none")
           $("#CloseButton").css("display","none")
           $("#OpenButton").css("display","block")
        });
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("#OpenPanel").click(function () {
        $("#Details1").animate({"left": 200},1000,function(){
           $("#Details1").css("display","block")
           $("#CloseButton").css("display","block")
           $("#OpenButton").css("display","none")
        });
    });
});


</script>

</body>
</html>

';
```

Comment: ignore my last post. this worked like a charm. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you cannot define a string in PHP using quotes (`"`) and then place some other quotes inside without escaping them. So you can do:

```
$var = "foo 'bar'";
```

or

```
$var = "foo \"bar\"";
```

or

```
$var = 'foo "bar"';
```

Just bear in mind that you cannot combine them because an unescaped quote inside a string declared with quotes simply ends the string declaration and most probably what is written after it will generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL-U in your browser and see which css is being loaded along the line of:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"
```

or try adding a slash

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"
```